# Unable to Verify user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel, so i started by creating a messaging application. User should be able to send message to each other. So i created migrations, seeds,models and also defined relationships in models. Everything was working fine. I was able to seed perfectly.

So i created a login page, applied validations. But now i'm unable to login.

Here is the route :

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'social'), function(){

    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'loginformshow', 'uses' => 'LoginformController@showLogin'));

    Route::post('loginform', array('as'=>'loginformdo', 'uses'=>'LoginformController@doLogin'));



    Route::get('loggedin', array('as'=>'loggedin', 'uses'=>'LoginformController@loggedin'));

});
```

Here's the respective method in controller

```
public function doLogin(){


        $rules = array('email'=> 'required|email', 'password'=>'required');

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

         if($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::to('social')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('password'));
         }else {
            $userdata = array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'));

            if(Auth::attempt($userdata)) {                  
                return Redirect::route('loggedin');
            }else echo "Invalid User";          
        }
    }
```

`Auth::attempt` is returning false every time and so the output is `Invalid User`.
i used `print_r` to check the data received in `$userdata` and it's showing correct credentials.

Here's the User model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function conversationsReply(){
        return $this->hasMany('ConversationReply', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) are db fields named email and passwords? 2) are your passwords correctly hashed?

Comment: 1) Yes. Field names are id, username, password, name, email, created_at, updated_at.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine then. Are you sure that passowrd you store in db is first hashed by `Hash::make('plain_text_password');` ?

Comment: How to check if passwords are correctly hashed?

i used:

echo $email = Input::get('email');
$password = Input::get('password');
echo $hashed_password = Hash::make("$password");

Password was different from the password stored in database(but yes, it was a hashed string).

Comment: Laravel uses Bcrypt for passwords so your password was hashed in other way, that is why auth fails. you should make sure that you has password like this: `$user->password = Hash::make('plain_password');`. I dont know how you create users but hope you will get the idea.

Comment: yes the password was hashed first before storing.

Comment: Does your user model correctly implement the required interface? posting the code for your model here would help

Comment: You should post the `User` model.